# Khan Academy API doesn't return data

Tags: khan-academy

I'm using the test_client2 included in the git repo. Making requests returns `<Response [200]>`, so apparently the system is working, but it doesn't print any data. What could cause this?

Full Code added here. The only changes I have made from the original code as pulled from GIT were to add CONSUMER_SECRET and CONSUMER_KEY values for the auth_token (which seems to work) and change one of the print functions to show explicitly where results start.

```
""" An interactive script for testing Khan Academy API Authentication. 

This is an example of how to use the /api/auth2 authentication flow.

See https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Authentication for
documentation.
"""

import cgi
import rauth
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import time
import webbrowser

# You can get a CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET for your app here:
# http://www.khanacademy.org/api-apps/register
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'Redacted but auth-token works'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'Redacted'

CALLBACK_BASE = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_URL = 'http://www.khanacademy.org'

DEFAULT_API_RESOURCE = '/api/v1/playlists'
VERIFIER = None


# Create the callback server that's used to set the oauth verifier after the
# request token is authorized.
def create_callback_server():
    class CallbackHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            global VERIFIER

            params = cgi.parse_qs(self.path.split('?', 1)[1],
                keep_blank_values=False)
            VERIFIER = params['oauth_verifier'][0]

            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('OAuth request token fetched and authorized;' +
                ' you can close this window.')

        def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
            pass

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((CALLBACK_BASE, 0), CallbackHandler)
    return server


# Make an authenticated API call using the given rauth session.
def get_api_resource(session):
    resource_url = raw_input("Resource relative url (e.g. %s): " %
        DEFAULT_API_RESOURCE) or DEFAULT_API_RESOURCE

    url = SERVER_URL + resource_url
    split_url = url.split('?', 1)
    params = {}

    # Separate out the URL's parameters, if applicable.
    if len(split_url) == 2:
        url = split_url[0]
        params = cgi.parse_qs(split_url[1], keep_blank_values=False)

    start = time.time()
    response = session.get(url, params=params)
    end = time.time()

    print "Result\n"
    print response
    print "\nTime: %ss\n" % (end - start)

def run_tests():
    global CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, SERVER_URL

    # Set consumer key, consumer secret, and server base URL from user input or
    # use default values.
    CONSUMER_KEY = raw_input("consumer key: ") or CONSUMER_KEY
    CONSUMER_SECRET = raw_input("consumer secret: ") or CONSUMER_SECRET
    SERVER_URL = raw_input("server base url: ") or SERVER_URL

    # Create an OAuth1Service using rauth.
    service = rauth.OAuth1Service(
           name='test',
           consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
           consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
           request_token_url=SERVER_URL + '/api/auth2/request_token',
           access_token_url=SERVER_URL + '/api/auth2/access_token',
           authorize_url=SERVER_URL + '/api/auth2/authorize',
           base_url=SERVER_URL + '/api/auth2')

    callback_server = create_callback_server()

    # 1. Get a request token.
    request_token, secret_request_token = service.get_request_token(
        params={'oauth_callback': 'http://%s:%d/' %
            (CALLBACK_BASE, callback_server.server_address[1])})

    # 2. Authorize your request token.
    authorize_url = service.get_authorize_url(request_token)
    webbrowser.open(authorize_url)

    callback_server.handle_request()
    callback_server.server_close()

    # 3. Get an access token.
    session = service.get_auth_session(request_token, secret_request_token,
        params={'oauth_verifier': VERIFIER})

    # Repeatedly prompt user for a resource and make authenticated API calls.
    print
    while(True):
        get_api_resource(session)


def main():
    run_tests()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your query is being sent correctly? Just because you get a 200 doesn't mean there are no errors. Khan is probably not displaying them on their api

Comment: How would I check that? The only edits I made to the code provided added user data.

Comment: Try running the query on the documentation first. See if it works. I assume you have set up an auth token and everything? Also, maybe posting the entire response from the site  will help

Comment: Auth token set up, I get the page that says OAuth request token fetched and authorized you can close this window.

Comment: Looks like the query on the documentation page [this one](https://api-explorer.khanacademy.org/) yes? is hanging. I used playlists and put basic-exponents as the name for the topic.

Comment: Where are you sending request from. We need more information. Are you requesting from some code or browser?

Comment: I'm using a python client. The one provided in the Khan Academy API under /examples/test_client2/test.py.

Comment: Please post your python code. Do you receive any errors from your code? Have you tried going to the link directly, like for badges you can do `https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/badges`

Comment: No errors in IDLE, and going to the url directly works.

Comment: If you can, it would be great if you could post a more [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- that will make it easier for people to figure out exactly what the problem you're encountering is.

Comment: Also, if you can attach the output you're getting, so that we can see if it's returning `None`, or `''`, or raising an error and not printing anything, that would be helpful too.

Comment: I actually gave up on solving this issue. I'm using selenium and a scraper instead.

Comment: Running your example query directly from a browser without any authentication works fine and returns about 11MB of data. It seems your authentication is somehow broken or the processing of the response. (I just used IE11 to open the URL https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/playlists)

Comment: Keep in mind scraping is probably against their TOS. Can't you just urrllib or curl it?